# Android - How to re-display Main Activity

Tags: java, android

I've searched for a solution to this problem but have been unable to find one.

The problem I have is that an alarm is sounded OK, however the `MainActivity` has closed and is not re-displayed .

How can I re-display the `MainActivity` in the following code:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    //this will update the UI with message
    AlarmActivity inst = AlarmActivity.instance();
    inst.setAlarmText("Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!");

    //this will sound the alarm tone
    //this will sound the alarm once, if you wish to
    //raise alarm in loop continuously then use MediaPlayer and setLooping(true)
    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null) {
        alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();

    //this will send a notification message
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            AlarmService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

}

The code is code that I downloaded as an example to work with from JavaPapers

http://javapapers.com/android/android-alarm-clock-tutorial/

Comment: Can you please post code for `AlarmService `??

Comment: The code is here: http://javapapers.com/android/android-alarm-clock-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion
 send a broadcast and have the reciever / or service start the activity for you

Answer (score 0):

I did attempt to use a broadcast, however it did not work, so likely what I did was incomplete.

While the following code did work (last 3 lines were added), it seems to me that it is wrong because I presume it creates a new instance of MainActivity. The MainActivity is AlarmActivity in the original version.

The code that "works" in AlarmService.java is as follows:

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    Log.d("AlarmService", "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
    alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder alarmNotificationBuilder = new   NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setContentTitle("Alarm").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    alarmNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(mPendingIntent);
    alarmNotificationManager.notify(1, alarmNotificationBuilder.build());
    Log.d("AlarmService", "Notification sent.");

    Intent mIntentMain = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    mIntentMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
    this.startActivity(mIntentMain);
}
```

The relevant code that I added is the last 3 lines. I put this into AlarmService.java because it extends IntentService. The original code posted in first posting (above) is from AlarmReceiver.java which extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver. I presume that what I should be doing is to cause the existing MainActivity to display rather than creating another.

Edited: 29-Sep-2016

Because the Main Activity may already be displayed, what I finally did to handle this was as follows:

> ```
>     if (fn_IsMainActivityDisplayed(this) == false) {
>         System.out.println("Main activity is not running. Now recreating");
>         try {
>             PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
>                     new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
>             mPendingIntent.send(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
>         } catch (Exception jExc) {
> ```

```
            System.out.println("AlarmService: PendingIntent failed: Error = " + jExc.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The code to determine if Main Activity is displayed was found on SO. I'm unsure if this is 100% correct, but it appears to work OK.